# Show a particular differential 1-form on $S^1$ is closed but not exact

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

> Consider the differential 1-form $\omega$ on $S^1$ given by $$\omega_{a}(\lambda (-a_2,a_1))=\lambda$$ for all $a=(a_1,a_2)$ in $S^1$. Show that $\omega$ is closed, but not exact.

I know I have to show that $d\omega=0$ and that there is a $0$-form $\alpha$ (i.e. a smooth function) such that $d\alpha=\omega$.  However, I am already struggling with the first part, since I only know how the form looks in a specific point. I thought I could write $\lambda (-a_2,a_1)=\lambda \begin{pmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a_1\\a_2 \end{pmatrix}$ and use the definition of the pullback, but that doesn't seem to help. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is $\lambda$?

Comment: I have no idea! The exercise does not specify it, so I'm assuming it is a scalar.

Comment: Any $X \in T_a S_1$ can be written as $\lambda(-a_2, a_1)$ for some real $\lambda$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**

1. (*Closedness*) $d\omega$ is a $2$-form on a $1$-manifold.
2. (*Inexactness*) If $\omega$ were exact, Stokes' Theorem (in this case, essentially the Fundamental Theorem for Path Integrals) would give $\int_{S^1} \omega = 0$.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that *every* $1$-form on a $1$-dimensional manifold is closed...

Comment: Yes, of course---I've updated my answer.