# An example about the differential form on $S^{1}$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I get this example from [Show a particular differential 1-form on $S^1$ is closed but not exact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3144674/show-a-particular-differential-1-form-on-s1-is-closed-but-not-exact), Consider the differential 1-form $\omega$ on $S^{1}$ given by
$$
\omega_{a}\left(\lambda\left(-a_{2}, a_{1}\right)\right)=\lambda
$$
$\text { Any } X \in T_{a} S_{1} \text { can be written as } \lambda\left(-a_{2}, a_{1}\right) \text { for some real } \lambda \text {. }$ for all $a=\left(a_{1}, a_{2}\right)$ in $S^{1}$. I want to show that $\omega$ is closed, but not exact.
my question are as follows (1)consider an atlas $U=\left\{\left(U_{\alpha}, \phi_{\alpha}\right)\right\}$ of $S^{1}$, the $S^{1}$ is a 1 dimensional manifold, so the tangent space $T_{p}\left(S^{1}\right)$at a point $p$ on $S^{1}$ is spanned by $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$, in the context of the problem, how to express an element $\lambda\left(-a_{2}, a_{1}\right) $ of the tangent space $T_{a}\left(S^{1}\right)$ at point $a$ in the form of $\lambda \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ ?(2) how to expresse this differential form with respect to the basis of 1-form $dt$ ? (3) how to find the differential of this differential form? (4) in the link the answer want to examine $\int_{S^1} \omega $ to deduce that this differential form is not exact, how to calculate this integral? I'm new to differential geometry so please give a complete computation, thanks you

Comment: $dx$ and $dy$ aren't a basis of $1$-forms on $S^1$ since $S^1$ is a 1-dimensional manifold. However, the form $\omega$ you've described is a basis of $\Omega^1 (S^1)$

Comment: Could you please tell me how to calculate the differential of this differential form? I know the definition of differential but I don't know how to calculate it @Didier

Comment: Its differential is a $2$-form on the $1$-dimensional manifold $S^1$: this should give you the answer. If you can't manage to find out, you might try to learn a bit more on differential forms

Comment: Could you please show me a detailed computation I understand the big picture of your answer but I still don't know how to calculate it @Didier

Comment: You've mentioned being new to differential geometry, but have you taken multivariable calculus, including line integrals, Green's theorem, and all that?

Comment: @吴yuer Suppose $\alpha$ is a $2$-form on a $1$-dimensional manifold $M$. Then for all $x\in M$, $\alpha_x$ is an alternating bilinear form on $T_xM$, which is a $1$-dimensional vector space. Can you go on?